# Bootstrap - place progress bar value on right side

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, progress-bar

> I want to make the Bootstrap progress bar value placed outside of the progress bar to the right.

I don't see this being possible but right now the only option I see is to set progress class a width of 100% minus the width of the value text.

What would be the best way to handle this?

[image: My Progress Bar]

Comment: Need code for context?

Answer (score 3):

I would use CSS tables to achieve that

HTML

```
<div class="progress-custom">
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 50%;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="progress-value">
        50%
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.progress-custom {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px; /*optionally same as the margin bottom of progress class*/
}

.progress-custom .progress{
    margin-bottom: 0;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.progress-custom .progress-value{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 1%; 
    padding: 0 4px; /*optionally*/
}
```

You can see it [here](http://codepen.io/tmg/pen/YqBWzK)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. It works fine. But, I am facing a scenario where I am having a table and I am trying to display 2 progress bars. In this case, both of them sinks in size. :(

Answer (score 0):

This would be a way. You need further styling to make it resemble te image you provided.

```css
.progress-bar span{
    text-indent: 420px;
    position: absolute;
    color: black;
}
.progress {
    width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
   <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 50%;">
       <span class="show">50% Complete</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code will work for you. Try this code. This code works for me.

*Happy Coding :-) ;-)*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
.progress{
border-radius: 10px ! important;
}
body{
padding-top: 20px;
}
</style>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid"><!--Container starts-->
<div class="row"><!--Row starts-->
<!--Progress Bar starts-->
<div class="col-xs-5">
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:50%">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--Progress Bar ends-->

<!--Percentage starts-->
<div class="col-xs-7">
<div class="pull-left">
50% <!--Add Your Percentage Here Dynamically-->
</div>
</div>
<!--Percentage ends-->

</div><!--Row ends-->
</div><!--Container ends-->

</body>
</html>
```